# Why do python list with a single entry give the 0th element for -1 index and 0 index?

Tags: python

On creating a list in python with just one element, when I try to get the -1 index element instead of getting list index out range error it is giving the 0th element.

```
some = ['something']
print(some[0]) # prints something
print(some[-1]) # prints something
```

Here is a link to the same: 
https://repl.it/@hearsid/SuperiorProudShoutcast

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A negative index means *nth from the right*. The zero-index of a one-element list is the same as the negative-one-index of a one-element list because the zeroth element is the same as the first element from the right.